# Avoiding Hasura sequential scan for query on large array relation

Tags: postgresql, hasura

How do I get Hasura to generate SQL that uses the index on `review.user_id`?

Here is the seemingly obvious way of getting a user's reviews. I've included a simplified version of the SQL that Hasura generates, which is a sub query approach rather than a JOIN of the `review` table on `user`:

```
# SELECT * FROM review 
#   WHERE user_id = (
#     SELECT id FROM "user" WHERE username = 'admin'
#   )
#   LIMIT 50
# This uses a sequential scan on `review` because Postgres
# can't know exactly what the subquery returns.
query ReviewsForUserSlow {
  user(where: { username: { _eq: "admin" } }) {
    reviews(limit: 50) {
      text
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a hack to get Hasura to generate SQL that does indeed use the `review.user_id` index. However, the caveat is that we need to make a round trip to Hasura to get the user ID in order to build this query:

```
# Simplification of the SQL Hasura generates:
# SELECT * FROM review 
#   WHERE user_id = '8f3547e4-c8a9-480f-991f-0798c02f2ba2'
#   LIMIT 50
query ReviewsForUserFast {
  review(
    limit: 50,
    where: {
      user_id: {
        _eq: "8f3547e4-c8a9-480f-991f-0798c02f2ba2"
      }
    }
  ) {
    text
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume there could be multiple users with username "admin"?  otherwise, in your second query, instead of a filter by id: `where: {user: {username: {_eq: "admin"}}}`

Comment: trial and error with `_aggregate` didn't work out

Comment: @avimoondra good thinking! but alas, still the same sequential scan. I actually thinking now that this is not a Hasura issue, but likely something to do with the data, we have millions of rows, so likely something isn't set up right. I'll update this answer if I find anything.